# How do I add a local custom gem with RVM or otherwise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation, rvm

I have to add a custom gem which is downloaded onto my local machine. How do I get it installed with Rails? I also have RVM installed. I tried pasting it into the gems folder but it doesn't get installed.

I believe to install a gem you need to run the `setup.rb` file but this gem doesn't seem to have that present. Any pointers to how to get this gem installed?

It's very important because I think this gem has dependencies and is stopping my project from running.

Answer (score 6):

Another option, in addition to @shingara's, is you can still add it to your Gemfile, but it will depend on everyone in your project team having the gem in the same location. Then you can do:

```
gem 'my_gem', '0.1.2.3', :path => '~/my_projects/my_gem_folder/'
```

And when you bundle, it'll pull and install from there.

If you're working on something by yourself, you can do this without worry that someone else who pulls down that project won't have that gem in the same location.

**EDIT** In addition to your comment for @shingara's answer, this works for not pointing straight to a .gem file, but to a folder that your gem resides in.

Comment: One other option, of course, is `gem "my_gem", "0.1.2.3", :git => "git://github.com/my_name/my_gem.git` [or some such](http://gembundler.com/git.html). As long as it's a gem you're comfortable putting a clone of online (or, who knows, in the OP's case it might be a beta version on GitHub), you can then distribute without fear of missing dependencies.

Comment: Fantastic! Be sure to mark off the answer for anyone else with the same problem can easily see what the solution is.

Comment: I had to git push to github and the install with a script/plugin install command only that seemed to actually work. But the other too suggestions were also great the one with bundler worked. But it did not load in my project ,very strange. but if i did bundle show and gem name it came up.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a gem by this path

```
gem install path/my_gem.gem
```

Comment: its not a gem file its a folder. how do i get rails to use it

Comment: You can add this folder in your GEM_PATH so